# SQL : to_tsvector on a specific value of a jsonB colonne

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search, supabase

I want to make a full search query on a spécific value of my jsonb like the format of the json is :

```
{
  "highlights": {
    "concise": null,
    "complete": null
  },
  "gist": {
    "concise": [
      {
        "text": "",
        "isHighlighted": false,
        "highlightID": ""
      }...
    ],
    "complete": null
  },
  "summary": {
  },
  "followup": {
  },
  "subjects": {
    ...
}
```

i want do my research on gist.concise

I have already tri like that but doesn't work :

```
SELECT
  audio.id
FROM
  audio
JOIN
  audio_json ON audio.id = audio_json.audio_id
WHERE
  to_tsvector(audio.name) @@ to_tsquery('ornithorinque')
  OR to_tsvector(audio.context::text) @@ to_tsquery('ornithorinque')
  OR to_tsvector(
    audio_json.analysis ->> 'gist' ->> 'concise'::text
  ) @@ to_tsquery('ornithorinque');
```

Comment: `doesn't work` means what exactly? You get the wrong results? An error? Computer caught fire?

Comment: HI sorry, the function simply returns me ```Success no rows``` when it should find one. On the other hand if my column was a simple json my code works but its a jsonb...

Comment: data is stored like this in my column :
```"{\"highlights\":{\"concise\":null,\"complete\":null},\"gist\":{\"concise\":[{\"text\":\"<span data-speaker-id=\\\"0\\\">SPEAKER_00</span> a confirmé l'efficacité exceptionnelle du component d'invitation de pilote, évaluée à 8000%, tout en admettant que seuls les tests sur Google ont été effectués. Il a exprimé sa gratitude pour la confiance de l'équipe, soulignant la performance du component. ornithorinque<br>\",\"isHighlighted\":false,\"highlightID\":\"gist-aa77edd8-b4ef-47cc-8808-e31c894ff63e\"}],...```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer is:
`to_tsvector((audio_json.analysis ->> 0)::jsonb ->> 'gist') @@ to_tsquery('ornithorinque')`

Comment: Don't you need to go deeper down the path? `audio_json.analysis#>>'{0,gist,concise,0,text}` [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ow51mPpy) Otherwise you're taking in adjacent keys and values on top of your target text - you could just as well cast the whole `jsonb` value to `text`, then `tsvector`.

Answer (score 0):

Built-in JSONPath you can use with `jsonb` offers [`like_regex`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-FILTER-EX-TABLE) filter expression: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ow51mPpy)

```sql
SELECT audio.id
FROM audio
JOIN audio_json ON audio.id = audio_json.audio_id
WHERE   audio_json.analysis
     @@ '$[0].gist.concise[0].text like_regex "ornithorinque"'
```

Here, `@@` is `jsonb` path [predicate check operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE).

`JSONB` is fast on its own and faster with an index, but queries with `like_regex` won't qualify for index support. It can be easily made faster if you extract your text and index it, or build an expression index: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/LEmKRc9C)

```sql
create extension if not exists pg_trgm;
create index idx_gin on audio_json 
  using gin((analysis#>>'{0,gist,concise,0,text}') gin_trgm_ops);

explain analyze verbose
select * from audio_json
where (analysis#>>'{0,gist,concise,0,text}') ~* 'ornithorinque';
```

In the demo, even though the jsonb `@@` operation also has a gin index available, it's unable to use it because of the being in use `like_regex`. Meanwhile, the `gin_trgm_ops` index makes the `~*` query about 1000x faster.

You can also use [full text search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-tables.html#TEXTSEARCH-TABLES-INDEX), which can be faster and more flexible: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/six1BuTu)

```sql
alter table audio_json add column text_tsv text generated always as 
  ((analysis#>>'{0,gist,concise,0,text}')) stored;
create index on audio_json 
  using gin(to_tsvector('french',text_tsv));
```